# Rabbit constantly digging and trying to bite

Tags: rabbits

hi I have a female rabbit of approx 6 months she is newzealnd Albino rabbit . Since last few days she has started digging a lot and also tries to bite us . So Kindly let me know what can be reason

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about how she usually lives? What types of enclosure does she have? What's in the enclosure? Does she live inside or outside most of the time? Has she been with a male or is she pregnant?

Comment: No she is not with Male she lives inside . I dont keep her in cage she lives and roams freely in my home. She has neither pregnant nor she has been with male.

Answer (score 1):

**Digging**:

Rabbits like to dig. Not only like it: They need to dig to stay healthy. You should add some kind of "sandbox" into the area she can use regularly. For example a simple box with an entry from above (for example with stairs or ramp) filled with soil, straw or similar.

[image: Digging box for rabbits]
[source: kaninchenwiese.de](https://www.kaninchenwiese.de/buddelkisten-fuer-kaninchen/)

If they can not follow their instincts, they will feel stressed and react with aggression. (In case the space for the rabbit is not big enough, rabbits would dig to overcome borders. Also if the rabbits do not feel save enough, they would dig to get a save place to hide.)

**Biting**:

Biting is a sign of feeling not comfortable with you near her. First you need to bring her to a vet to verify if she has no health reasons for feeling uncomfortable, like pain. Second you need to make her feeling comfortable with persons around: include places to hide in her area (best: something she can hide inside and have a secure look to persons outside, like this kind of wooden boxes with spaces between the boards). Do not pick her up from above (she would associate this with a bird of prey, fight and remember you in a bad manner). And you need to give her a rabbit as companion. Humans are not able to exchange a real rabbit, even if they would be there 24/7 and would really try. The rabbit would not understand the body language of the human and so feel really lonely, especially because rabbits are animals with a big family in the nature. The rabbits share the task to look out for dangers, but one alone feels the pressure to do this all time without breaks. (Females are most easy to accompany with males, but one of them **need to be spayed**!)

I like really that your rabbit can roam freely! Enough space is most times the problem where I live. But if you really want a happy rabbit, you need a second one. Beneath the spaying two of them would not cause more effort than one alone, more the other way around, because the rabbits would entertain themself when no human is around and so they would not start to behave bad.

Comment: Read also this question: [Rabbit alone, good idea?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25974/bunny-alone-good-idea)